# Is it possible to use a callback table which contains {sub,super}class function pointers?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, pointer-to-member

I currently have a connection object which performs processing for incoming commands requests.  Each command is a string which is mapped to a callback method using an unordered map.  A trimmed down example which illustrates the core function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

class Conn;
typedef void (Conn::*ProcFn)();

class Conn
{
  private:
  void proc_ping();

  static const std::unordered_map<std::string, ProcFn> handlers;

  public:
  void simulate();
};

const std::unordered_map<std::string, ProcFn> Conn::handlers = {
  std::pair("ping", &Conn::proc_ping)
};

void Conn::proc_ping()
{
  std::cout << "ping!" << std::endl;
}

void Conn::simulate()
{
  auto pfn = handlers.at("ping");

  std::invoke(pfn, this);
}

int main()
{
  Conn c;

  c.simulate();
}
```

This works fine, but I realized that I'll need multiple different network interfaces which have different major roles (think "management interface" vs "client data interface") so I made a copy of the Conn class into ConnMgmt and ConnData.  However, it quickly became apparent that there was was enough overlap among the handlers that it made sense to create a common class for the two.

What I want to to is to create a ConnBase which contains the shared functionality of ConnMgmt and ConnData.

My question pertains to the callback function table.

I want to have a single table to map the command request strings to callback functions, *but* I would like the method pointers to be able to refer to methods in the derived classes.  I.e. I have a single dispatcher for both the ConnBase and ConnMgmt or ConnBase and ConnData (depending on which interface is being called).

This is [nonfunctional] code which illustrates the gist of what I would like to accomplish:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

class ConnBase;
typedef void (ConnBase::*ProcFn)();

class ConnBase
{
  protected:
  void proc_ping();
};

void ConnBase::proc_ping()
{
  std::cout << "ping!" << std::endl;
}

class ConnMgmt : public ConnBase
{
  protected:
  static const std::unordered_map<std::string, ProcFn> handlers;

  void proc_create_user();

  public:
  void simulate();
};

void ConnMgmt::proc_create_user()
{
  std::cout << "create user!" << std::endl;
}

const std::unordered_map<std::string, ProcFn> ConnMgmt::handlers = {
  std::pair("ping", &ConnBase::proc_ping),
  std::pair("create_user", &ConnMgmt::proc_create_user)
};

void ConnMgmt::simulate()
{
  auto pfn = handlers.at("ping");

  std::invoke(pfn, this);

  pfn = handlers.at("create_user");

  std::invoke(pfn, this);
}

int main()
{
  ConnMgmt c;

  c.simulate();
}
```

This code is broken in several ways, but I'm specifically wondering if:

- Is the idea of having a "ConnMgmt::handlers" table which contains pointers to methods in both ConnBase and ConnMgmt fundamentally broken?  The compiler croaks, saying the pointer is of wrong type.
- If there's a way to cast it which fixes the problem, will I have entered into the domain of undefined behavior (or worse)?.  I have read that it "should" be possible to use a method pointer type for subclasses, but that there are caveats relating to virtual classes (and on that note: There *are* virtual functions in the classes, but none of the handler functions will be virtual).
- Given what I want to accomplish (create a string-to-method dispatcher where the methods may reside in different classes (albeit always belonging to the same class hierarchy)), is there some idiomatic C++17 way to do it?

(No boost allowed).

Comment: Something like [function_view](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html#function_view) could be a good fit, assuming you're not using `std::function` for performance reasons?

Comment: You need to make your methods virtual and place them all in your base class. Override as needed. Failing that, store bound `std::function`s instead of built-in function pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you need with a few changes.

If you change the type of `ProcFn` to

```
typedef void (ConnMgmt::*ProcFn)();
```

then you are almost ready to construct your `ConnMgmt::handlers` table.  You need to specify the types for `std::pair`.  Then the remaining issue is that `ConnBase::proc_ping` is protected, and not accessible.  The way to fix that is to change the reference to be `ConnMgmt::proc_ping`.

const std::unordered_map ConnMgmt::handlers = {
  std::pair("ping", &ConnMgmt::proc_ping),
  std::pair("create_user", &ConnMgmt::proc_create_user)
};

Each derived class will need their own handlers table and `ProcFn` typedefs.